# When does plank during stop working for aesthetic purposes?

Tags: bodybuilding, abdominals

I understand that for any given exercise, the rep range for power is 1-3, strength is around 5, hypertrophy is around 8, and 12+ is for endurance. How does this related to planks?

E.g. how long should I be able to hold a plank position before adding weights? 30 seconds? 1 minute? 2 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you're referring to *reps*, but the plank is an isometric exercise. For that reason, a single plank might better be seen as a *set*.

Another view I'd like to offer is that the actual time you do the plank might be more suited to be likened to reps. Rough example of what I mean:

- 120s bodyweight plank would improve mainly endurance -> low intensity (like high reps, low weight)
- 10s plank with 30kg of weight would improve mainly strength -> high intensity (like low reps, high weight)

So since you're going for looks/hypertrophy you should probably be able to hold the plank for ~1min before you add weight. Otherwise you'd train more for short-term strength.

Answer (score 2):

If you can do a standard plank for 1 minute.  It's time to make it harder.
Move to a Swiss ball.  Put your feet on an upside down bosu.  Lots of options...

Answer (score 2):

The standard measurement for fitness is 60 - 90 seconds. If you can consistently perform plank *(with good form)* for this duration without breaking a sweat, it's time to increase the pressure. 
 
If you can really perform 120 seconds without breaking a sweat, it's time to bring out the big guns:

- Adding weights.
- Using instability balls.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the minute figure pretty consistently. What to do next depends on who you talk to, but a lot of people seem to be suggesting [dynamic plank techniques](http://q.equinox.com/articles/2013/09/plank-workout%E2%80%8E) where you start in a plank or plank-like position and transition back and forth using different movements.